# Constraint validator to validate a field in Child class based on another field in Parent class

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have 2 Domain classes like `ParentClass` and `ChildClass`. 
(ParentClass contains a list of Child class objects in Array list.)

I created separate Validator classes for ParentClass and ChildClass to do the custom validations.

Example validator class for the Parent class:

```
    public class ParentClassValidator implements 
ConstraintValidator<ValidatedByParentClassInterface, ParentClass> {
```

and then override the `isValid()` method of `ConstraintValidator`,

```
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final ParentClass parentClass, 
                     final ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
```

Example validator class for the Child class:

```
public class ChildClassValidator implements 
    ConstraintValidator<ValidatedByChildClassInterface, ChildClass> {
```

and then override the `isValid()` method of `ConstraintValidator`,

```
    @Override
            public boolean isValid(final ChildClass childClass, 
               final ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) { 
   //No option to pass Parent class object here?
```

One of the fields in my Child class need to be validated based on the value of the field in Parent class. But the `isValid()` method of ConstraintValidator(https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html) has only 2 arguments so how do I pass the ParentClass object here in my ChildClassValidator?

or Should I use a `for` loop in my ParentClassValidator to validate this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like using a `for` loop in my ParentClassValidator to validate this scenario is the only possible solution

So, instead of having 2 validators i.e 1 for parent class and 1 for chid class, it is better to put all the custom validations(including child class validations) in the parent class validator